# Visual Studio 2019 Data Source Window Doesn't Allow Me To Add A Database File

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to connect a database to my C# Windows Form Application, but the data sources window says that

> This window is not supported for the selected project.

How can I fix this? I have the data connection set in the server explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ( Create a new project ) window select Windows Form App(.NET **Framework**)
NOT Windows Form App (.NET)

Comment: Yes, this worked! I can't believe I missed that.